# Remove auto generated html element with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

im using a cms that auto generated blank html elements in the post content of blog:

```
<div class="post-list-item-content">                            
  <div> 

   <h2 style="text-align: center;"></h2> 
   <h2>&nbsp;</h2>

   <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2> 

   <h2 style="text-align: center;">
     <img src="../img/img-001.jpg" alt="img-001.jpg" width="699" height="393">
   </h2>

   <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

I want to remove the two h2 elements (one is empty, the other is space) with JQuery but i must check if those h2 is empty or not blank first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/), like:

```
var emptyH2 = $('h2').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()).length == 0
});

emptyH2.remove();
```

**Update::**
If the `h2` tag contains nested element then .[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) with some regex can be used, like:

```
var emptyH2 = $('h2').filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return ($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
});
emptyH2.remove();
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9zwcquxs/)

Comment: Hi thank you, your solution works but unfortunately there's a h2 contains an image tag with no text inside, this solution also remove that h2. Can you modify your solution abit to fix it?

Comment: I did, please check

Comment: @Lee see my added answer. This works with h2 elements containing nested html tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
    if($("h2").html().trim() == ""){

       $("h2").empty();
       //OR
       $("h2").remove() // will remove complete DOM

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('h2').filter(function(i,e){ return $.trim($(e).text()) == ''}).remove();
```

Comment: Do you really think that'll work for both the cases?

Comment: fixed my solution, now it goes